# I can access my fun inside the ViewHolder from the adapter

Tags: function, kotlin, adapter, inner-classes, android-viewholder

I try to call fun bind declared in the  inner class LaunchesViewHolder from onBindViewHolder() but I got error "Unresolved resource bind"
I was trying with an other variable x, just to see, same problem

`````
class LaunchesAdapter(private val dataSet: List<LaunchItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


   inner class LaunchesViewHolder( val binding: LaunchesItemLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val x = 0
        public fun bind(currentLaunch: LaunchItem) {
           //do something
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return LaunchesViewHolder(
            LaunchesItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
     holder.bind(dataSet[position]) => error unresolved resource bind 
     holder.x =1 => error unresolved resource x
}


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.size
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onBindViewHolder` you should use your specific `ViewHolder`, that is `LaunchesViewHolder` and not the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Please see code below.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LaunchesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(dataSet[position])
}
```

Edited:
You need to specify the class you override too

```
class LaunchesAdapter(private val dataSet: List<LaunchItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LaunchesAdapter.LaunchesViewHolder>() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with
(holder as LaunchesViewHolder).bind(dataSet[position])
instead of holder.bind(dataSet[position])

see more details https://www.section.io/engineering-education/implementing-multiple-viewholders-in-android-using-kotlin/